# Maximum of the product of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Suppose I have two bounded, non-negative, continuous functions $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that
$$\max_{x\in[a,b]}(f(x)g(x))\leq \max_{x\in[a,b]}(f(x))\max_{x\in[a,b]}(g(x)).$$
I have played around with some examples and am having a hard time finding an example for which this breaks.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both positive you get $f(x)g(x)\le (\max\limits_{y\in [a,b]} f(y)) (\max\limits_{y\in [a,b]} g(y))$. The right hand sind is thus an upper bound of all possible left hand sides.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! You have convinced me!

Comment: 1. Continuous functions on $[a,b]$ are automatically bounded. 2. It is true for any two bounded, non-negative functions if you replace $\max$ by $\sup$.